# get element by class name

Tags: jquery, opacity

I wanna know how to get element by class name, this is html code

```
<div class="header" id="parent">

        <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="head_container">
                <img src="images/logo_picture.png" alt="" title="" class="logopic" />
                <img src="images/logo_text.png" alt="" title="" class="logotext" />
                <img src="images/head_line.jpg" title="" alt="" class="head_line" />

            </div>

    </div>
```

This is jquery and this is problem, I have code with getEelementById, but I wanna using getElementByClass. This is method to use opacity on any element and prevent the child elements form inheriting the opacity. I will use five or six time class parent, so I need getElementByClass method

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function thatsNotYoChild(parentID) {

    var parent           = document.getElementById(parentID),
        children         = parent.innerHTML,
        wrappedChildren  = '<div id="children" class="children">' + children + '</div>',
        x, y, w, newParent, clonedChild, clonedChildOld;

    parent.innerHTML = wrappedChildren;
    clonedChild = document.getElementById('children').cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementById('children').id = 'children-old';
    clonedChildOld = document.getElementById('children-old');
    newParent = parent.parentNode;

    newParent.appendChild(clonedChild);
    clonedChildOld.style.opacity = '0';
    clonedChildOld.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=0)';

    function doCoords () {
      x = clonedChildOld.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      y = clonedChildOld.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      if (clonedChildOld.getBoundingClientRect().width) {
        w = clonedChildOld.getBoundingClientRect().width; // for modern browsers
      } else {
        w = clonedChildOld.offsetWidth; // for oldIE
      }

      clonedChild.style.position = 'absolute';
      clonedChild.style.left = x + 'px';
      clonedChild.style.top = y + 'px';
      clonedChild.style.width = w + 'px';
    }

    window.onresize = function () {

      doCoords();

    };

    doCoords();

}


thatsNotYoChild('parent');
});
```

Comment: You have jQuery and you're using `document.getElementById` etc? How about using jQuery?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using jquery like $('.head_container') or any class?

Comment: it's okay but everything get opacity, even child element, I want my header background opacity not the logo, text inside of div header.

Answer (score 2):

Use a class selector. jQuery uses selectors similar to CSS, so:

```
$('.child')
```

will select all elements with a class of `child`.

For IDs, prefix the ID with the `#` character:

```
$('#parent')
```

Answer (score 0):

> I wanna know how to get element by class name

Just use [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you simply use jquery?

```
$(".class").css({opacity:1});
```

*Solution to your problem:*

What you want to do is impossible. Child will always inherit opacity of the parent. This makes allot of sense to me personally.

What you can do is make two background images with different opacity-transparency, and switch background-image using jquery, istead of changing opacity itself.

Do you understand? This is the only way to achieve what you want.

```
$(".class").css({"background-image":"url('opacity-0.png')"});
$(".class").css({"background-image":"url('opacity-1.png')"});
```

Comment: in my case, $(".header").css({opacity:1}); all div class header get opacity, logo, text and others, do you understand now ?

Comment: @RagingBull What you want to do is impossible. Child will always inherit opacity of the parent. What you can do is make two background images with different opacity, and switch background-image using jquery, istead of changing opacity itself. Do you understand? This is the only way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a live example that demonstrates how to select class elements:

<kbd>[Working jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/DRdyy/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<div class="header" id="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="head_container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" title="" class="logopic" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" title="" class="logotext" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" title="" alt="" class="head_line" />
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Click Me">
```

**javascript/jQuery:**

```
//Gets any div when clicked
$('div').click(function(e) {
    alert('Class name is: ' + $(this).attr('class') );
    e.stopPropagation();
});

//Gets any div with class="child" when clicked
$('.child').click(function(){
    alert('You clicked the CHILD div');
});

//When click button, makes div with class="child" turn red
$('#mybutt').click(function(){
    $('.child').css({'background-color':'red'});
});
```